# How do I make the XPages REST control return the overall number of filtered matches?

Tags: xpages

I am calling an ExtLib REST service which is using a search term to filter the results.

There is no indication of the overall number of results found in the JSON returned

I want to be able to add a key at the top of the return results to be something like "searchCount="

How can that be easily achieved without having to do a separate FTSearch and do a dc.count?

```
{
    "@timestamp":"2012-08-02T22:47:15Z",
    "@toplevelentries":1301,
    "items":
    [
      {
          "@entryid":"877-06C896874946365E85257A4E00537736",
          "@unid":"06C896874946365E85257A4E00537736",
          "@noteid":"D26",
          "@position":"877",
          "@read":true,
          "@siblings":1298,
          "firstname":"Mary",
          "lastname":"Richard",
          "address":"44 Huntz Lane",
          "city":"QUINCY",
          "state":"MA"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a dojo store for fetching the results? The store knows how many results you will get.

To define your own output I recommend using a xe:customRestService. You can search the view in here and return the results in whatever format you like.